# How can I view all the content of redmine, such as projects and tickets, easily on the screen?

Tags: redmine

I'm using REDMINE.
I have a list of projects on the screen.
Is it possible to add details of the ticket content to this screen?
I'd like to look over the screen at once instead of clicking with the mouse, how do I do that?
Also, if you have any plugins or useful tips and so on, please let me know.

Comment: If you want to know the project name with ticket then you can use https://redmineurl/issues also there are plugins available but you need to describe more info about what you really want to achieve then I can suggest some plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Tamazawa, I believe you might be referring to "My Page" of Redmine where you could use widgets to decide what you see on that dashboard - keep in mind that such dashboard s project independent, so it can display issues from many projects that you are a member of on 1 screen.

For instance from My Page, you should be able to select an "Issues" widget to **Add** and set it up to pull a list of items to display using a saved custom query.

[image]

That should give you a snapshot of tasks at hand, without the need to click around the screen too much.

You may need to set up your saved query such that:

- Description  and / or
- Last notes

are checked (if you want to see issues at a glance, without the need to open each one separately).
[image]

Alternatively, you can skip that "My Page" idea altogether, if you're ok with just opening a saved query with *Description* and / or *Last notes* selected.